# ServiceNow em_event table additional_Info field is returning [object Object]

Tags: powershell, rest, servicenow

We are using Rest API via PowerShell (Invoke-RestMethod), in order to insert records in ServiceNow event [em_event] table with a single call, using the web service API.

We successfully inserting events to the em_event table,
but the only problem is with the **additional_info** field.

For some reason,

The JSON structure of my PowerShell script,
Is causing the output of **additional_info**, to return as an Object and Not as JSON string.

And as a result,
The values in **additional_info** not showing properly, but instead as [object Object]:
[image: ServiceNow EM]

This is the JSON structure in my PowerShell script:

```
# Specify request body
$body = @"
{   "records":  
[
     {
     "source":"MyClass",
     "event_class":"$AtargetResourceType",
     "resource":"$AtargetResourceType",
     "node":"$AtargetResourceName",
     "metric_name":"$Aname",
     "type":"$AsignalType",
     "severity":"$Aseverity",
     "message_key":"$Aid",
     "u_mc_object":"$AtargetResource",
     "description":"$Adescription",
     "additional_info":"{  
                            'u_mc_object_class':'$AsourceCreatedId',
                            'u_mc_parameter':'$AmetricName',
                            'u_mc_parameter_value':'$AmetricValue'
                        }"
      }     
   ]
}
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

image which you have posted is not opening. but according to your issue below line will return string value for additional_info:

```
($body|ConvertFrom-Json).records.additional_info
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on your answer? where do i need to use this line in my JSON structure? and should i need to use ConvertTo-Json ? (**cmdlet converts any object to a string in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format**)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue sending the request using Postman, I was sending the request like this:

```
{   "records":  
[
     {
     "source":"BMC TrueSight",
     "type":"Incident from trusight",
     "severity":"1",
     "description":"This is a test from WEB SERVICE API ERROR",
     "additional_info":{  
                        "status":"new",
                        "description":"This is a descriotion from additional information",
                        "category":"41",
                        "subcategory": "test",
                        "company": "test",
                        "business_service":"test"
                        }
      }     
   ]
}
```

and it showed [object][object] in the additional information field, what I did was sent that field as a string like this:

```
"additional_info": "{\"assignee_group\":\"ETSS\/UNIX99\",\"status\":\"new\",\"description\":\"This is a descriotion from additional information\",\"category\":\"41\",\"subcategory\":\"test\",\"company\":\"test\",\"business_service\":\"
}
```

You only need to convert the JSON into a string.